# Building a neural network chess engine

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, theano

I am building a single layer NN to play chess.

The input is a matrix[n,m] of n training set, 64 features each where each feature represents a square.

The training output is a matrix[n,1] where each output is a centipawn score obtained from stockfish. For example, the score can be 100, -200, 1405, etc etc.

I want to build this NN that has 64 input nodes, 500 hidden nodes, and 1 output node for outputting a score.

I know that NN is used for classification, but I was wondering if I can build a NN that can output arbitrary integers as well?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, a neural network can output arbitrary integers.

Comment: So... I can build the said network. with 1 output node that just prints out 1 arbitrary number based on trained weights?? Thats good news... Thanks

Comment: I never said that. I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: My question was I want to build this NN that has 64 input nodes, 500 hidden nodes, and 1 output node for outputting a score (arbitrary integer). Is this doable?

Comment: I'm thinking about this idea. However I don't understand how you are planning to train the system. I would define training data as matrix[n,m,c] where c represents the centipawn score for the given board layout. You can't have an output that you don't feed in training if you do supervised training. If your intention is to predict the centipawn value you should include it in the training data. Training only returns the weights and the Neural Network Structure in the case you use a genetic model.

Comment: matrix[n,m,c] ? What is your n and m? 

I do have centipawn values for training. I used stockfish to obtain the value.

Comment: Yes. It's just a simple regression-like NN. But researching a bit more the basics of NNs seems to be important here. There is a lot you can do wrong. One obvious decision is which kind of activation-functions are in use. I would use something like a tanh activation at the output which restricts the output to (-1,1). This will be much better that predicting these values in their raw state but need some preprocessing.

Comment: I dont think I can restrict the output between -1,1. Since the training output in centipawn can be greater or less than that.